# Application Helper rails 4 in cells 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-cells

I am using cells 4 to render a login form in rails 4,
and I get the following error:

```
'undefined local variable or method `current_user' for <PopupLoginCell:0xbbd32e74>'
```

I have tried including `include ApplicationHelper`.
Please help me.

```
#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  #protect_from_forgery

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end


# show.haml
- unless user_signed_in?
  .popup-login
    = form_for(@user, url:user_session_path) do |f|
      %dl
        %dt= f.label :email
        %dd= f.email_field :email
        %dt= f.label :password
        %dd= f.password_field :password
      = f.submit 'Login'
   :javascript
     $('.header__login-button a').click(function(){
       $('.popup-login').css({ 'display' : 'block'});
     });
#pop_up_login_cell.rb
class PopupLoginCell < Cell::ViewModel
  # helper tự định nghĩa
  include ApplicationHelper


  def show
    @user = User.new unless current_user.present?
    render
  end

end
```

Comment: Try `include ApplicationController` instead.

Comment: Hi Pavan,  error show => 'wrong argument type Class (expected Module)'

Comment: @khavq, did you ever solve this? Also, you may want to tag this question with the rails-cells tag to get more eyeballs.

Answer (score 1):

In you cell class you must include the Devise helpers:

```
class PopupLoginCell < Cell::ViewModel
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  helper_method :current_user

  # Your class code
end
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass current_user to cell as an option

```
#haml/slim
= cell(PopupLoginCell, my_model, current_user: current_user)
#erb
<%= cell(PopupLoginCell, my_model, current_user: current_user) %>
```

[From official docs](http://trailblazer.to/gems/cells/api.html#options)